# How to read categorical columns with pandas' read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, readfile, categorical-data

I have tried passing the `dtype` parameter with `read_csv` as `dtype={n: pandas.Categorical}` but this does not work properly (the result is an Object). [The manual is unclear](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Is it possible to read categorical columns with `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: pandas 21.0 has a [CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0210-enhancements-categorical-dtype); the example `read_csv(...)` there does what you want.

Comment: For simple uses-cases, use `dtype='category'`, not what you wrote.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In version [`0.19.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#read-csv-supports-parsing-categorical-directly) you can use parameter `dtype='category'` in `read_csv`:

```
data = 'col1,col2,col3\na,b,1\na,b,2\nc,d,3'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), dtype='category')
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b    1
1    a    b    2
2    c    d    3

print (df.dtypes)
col1    category
col2    category
col3    category
dtype: object
```

If want specify column for category use `dtype` with dictionary:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), dtype={'col1':'category'})
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    b     1
1    a    b     2
2    c    d     3

print (df.dtypes)
col1    category
col2      object
col3       int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: I think yes, use `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dtype={'col1':'category'}, index_col='col1')`

Comment: This just made my day.

Answer (score 4):

It's been over 8 years since this question was posted but `dtype={n: pandas.Categorical}` doesn't work because `pd.Categorical` is a top-level function that converts a column into a category dtype, not the dtype instance itself. You can use `pd.CategoricalDtype()` for that.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv", dtype=pd.CategoricalDtype())
```

For a specific column, e.g. `col1`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv", dtype={'col1': pd.CategoricalDtype()})
```

The advantage of explicitly using the dtype instance (over passing the shortcut `'category'`) is because you can do 2 things:

- pass specific categories (some valid categories may not exist in the data yet). This is especially important because trying to change values in a categorical column by a value that does not exist as a category raises a special error: `TypeError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category (b), set the categories first`. To prevent this error altogether, you can pass the list of categories in the beginning.
- specify if it's ordered or not

Using the example in @jezrael's answer, the following code demonstrates an example:

```py
import io
data = 'col1,col2,col3\na,b,1\na,b,2\nc,d,3'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), dtype={'col1': pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['c', 'b', 'a'], ordered=True)})
```

Then when we inspect `df['col1']` closer:

```py
df['col1']

0    a
1    a
2    c
Name: col1, dtype: category                # <--- was read in as categorical dtype
Categories (3, object): ['c' < 'b' < 'a']  # <--- 'b' is a category even though it doesn't exist in the column yet
```