# Pandas categorical columns to factorize tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dask, categorical-data

I am working on a huge denormalized table on a SQL server (10 columns x 130m rows). Take this as data example :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' :  ['pending', 'pending','pending', 'canceled','canceled','canceled', 'confirmed', 'confirmed','confirmed'],
    'clientId' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B','C'],
    'partner' :  ['A', np.nan,'C', 'A',np.nan,'C', 'A', np.nan,'C'],
    'product' : ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
    'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_3', 'brand_3'],
    'gmv' : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})

data = data.astype({'partner':'category','status':'category','product':'category', 'brand':'category'})
```

As you can see, many of it columns are categories/strings that could be factorize (replaced by a small int identification to another x.1 join).

My question is if there is a easy way to extract another "dataframe" from each category columns and <s>factory</s> factorize the main table, so the bytes transmitted over a single query could be faster! Is there any easy library for it?

I would expect to get this output:

```
    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'status' :  ['1', '1','1', '2','2','2', '3', '3','3'],
        'clientId' : ['1', '2', '3', '1', '4', '3', '1', '2','3'],
        'partner' :  ['A', np.nan,'C', 'A',np.nan,'C', 'A', np.nan,'C'],
        'product' : ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
        'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_3', 'brand_3'],
        'gmv' : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})
    
status_df = {1 : 'pending', 2:'canceled', 3:'confirmed'} 
clientid = {1 : 'A', 2:'B', 3:'C', 4:'D'}
```

and so on!

**Bonus question! My table is big, so I probably would need to apply something using DASK.**

Comment: [`read_csv()` supports specifying dtype='category' since 0.19](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.19.0.html). Try reading your categorical columns in directly as such, that should keep CPU and memory demands down. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272300/how-to-read-categorical-columns-with-pandas-read-csv). You shouldn't need dask.

Comment: When you say "huge denormalized table", how many rows and columns, and how many of the columns are int, float, categorical (with how many levels?), string. Also, only read in only the columns you want with `read_csv()` parameter `usecols=['B','F','K'...]`, and constrain their dtypes (int/float/category), don't read in tons of junk unnecessary columns as 'object', if your code won't ever need them. Show us the output of `data.info()`

Comment: You can replicate the performance issue without giving us your data by generating a huge example using seeded-random data.

Comment: About 10 columns and 130 million rows. Pandas break as soon as I start to make some group bys lol.

Comment: Columns are mostly categorical, but the data has been saved now on a sql server for a power bi connection. That's why I have been studying ways to improve the read performance

Comment: The issue here is being caused by one huge `read_sql()` operation without chunking, show us your code from `read_sql()` onwards. In particular make sure you use the [`chunksize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) parameter.

Comment: Once you fix that, what is the calculation you are trying to do downstream of this? An aggregation? A select operation? A crosstabulation? etc. Can that operation also be chunked?

Comment: The table is going to feed some power bi dashboards. They have some aggregation but all inside pwbi features

Comment: Ok but what's the next line of Python code? Are you running that Python inside PowerBI, or do you export the data to PowerBI? Either way, we need to see what line of code is next. Otherwise, we have no context about what you're doing with the data, so we don't know what to measure or fix.

Comment: **Please use [`chunksize` parameter with`read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)** like I suggested. Try values from 64KB...1MB Measure your memory use before and after and tell us if it improves them. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107953/how-to-create-a-large-pandas-dataframe-from-an-sql-query-without-running-out-of)

Comment: My SQL read is done by power bi. I am using python to create and save the table to SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) to do this. For example:

```
codes, uniques = pd.factorize(data['status'])
data['status'] = codes
status_df = pd.DataFrame(uniques)
```

Output (data):

```
   status clientId partner    product    brand  gmv
0       0        A       A  afiliates  brand_1  100
1       0        B     NaN   pre-paid  brand_2  100
2       0        C       C   giftcard  brand_3  100
3       1        A       A  afiliates  brand_1  100
4       1        D     NaN   pre-paid  brand_2  100
5       1        C       C   giftcard  brand_3  100
6       2        A       A  afiliates  brand_1  100
7       2        B     NaN   pre-paid  brand_3  100
8       2        C       C   giftcard  brand_3  100
```

Output (status_df):

```
           0
0    pending
1   canceled
2  confirmed
```

For columns like `partner`, where there are `NaN` values, you can choose to have them replaced with `-1` (the default behaviour), or to have `NaN` included in `partner_df` (along with its own index) by specifying `use_na_sentinel=False`.

Comment: @FábioRB is this what you were trying to achieve? Or had you already done this and were looking for an alternate solution?

Comment: I haven't tested the suggestions yet.

Comment: @FábioRB ah sorry, I misinterpreted your comments on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the built-in [categorical data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) in Pandas?

To demonstrate this I will make the example dataframe you provided 100 times bigger:

```
data = pd.concat([data]*100).reset_index()
assert data.shape == (900, 6)
```

Then compare memory usage before:

```
print(data.memory_usage(index=False))

status      7200
clientId    7200
partner     7200
product     7200
brand       7200
gmv         7200
dtype: int64
```

Now convert some of the columns to categorical type:

```
cols_to_convert = ['status', 'clientId', 'partner', 'product', 'brand']
for col in cols_to_convert:
    data[col] = data[col].astype('category')
```

Then see the memory usage after:

```
status      1032
clientId    1104
partner     1024
product     1032
brand       1032
gmv         7200
dtype: int64
```

Would this achieve what you want?  I'm sure Dask has the same features.

If you want to get the categories and category lookup values you can access them as follows:

```
clientId_categories = data['clientId'].cat.categories
clientId_codes = data['clientId'].cat.codes
print(clientId_categories)
print(clientId_codes[:5])
```

```
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    3
dtype: int8
```

Comment: I already used categorical dtype os pandas dask when creating the data frame,  but such data is exported to a SQL server and loses it categories and become strings.

Comment: I was thinking of use auxiliary tables to create a categories table translation by using something like factorize

Comment: Ah okay.  It was not clear in your question that you were already using the categorial dtype.

Comment: My issue regards that my data frame, manly categorical data, is now on a sql server that will feed my power bi report. I am working on ways to enhance the data reading taking into consideration that most of the data is categorical